# css -webkit-radial-gradient ghost strikethrough line

Tags: css, google-chrome

Im having some weird issues in chrome.
I dont use images, everything is done by css only.
Check the image below. How can i remove the vertical line (sometimes also a horizontal line appears)?

[image: unexplained striketrough line]

Im trying to get rounded corners but to the inside.
Here are the code pieces.

```
<div class="modal"> the content goes here </div>
```

The class is:

```
.modal {
background:
        -moz-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
        -moz-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
        -moz-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
        -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px);
    background:
         -o-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
         -o-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
         -o-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
         -o-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px);
    background:
         -webkit-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
         -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
         -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px),
         -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba({{ settings.signup_bg_color }},0) 24px, {{ settings.signup_bg_color }} 25px);

    background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
    -moz-background-size: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

I found the example [here](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/)
If i remove the rounded corners, the ghost line disappears.

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but you can also achieve this effect with an SVG background.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @JCOC611 I've never thought of that. If i don't fix this issue, i might do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase very slightly the size of the gradients, say 50.1%

```
    background-size: 50.1% 50.1%;
```

The problem comes from a size of the div that once divided by 2, leaves a small zone in the center not covered by the backgrounds

Comment: It works. background-size: 50.2% 50.2%; did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Happy that it helped ! By the way, I think that you can drop safely -moz-background-size and -webkit-background-size